# Hex number operations in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, binary, hex

I am making an application in C# and I have hex numbers such as `0x0FF8,0xFFFA` etc.

Here I want only `12 bit` from right to left. Suppose I have a number as `0x0FF8`.
So I just want to make operation on `FF8.(12 bits)`, and this is signed number.

It is the decimal number is `-8`. In my application I have to first find whether number is negative or not? And after that its value.

I am not getting how to do it in C# efficiently as I have to do it very fast.
The number representation is as `0x0FF8= -8` please see the link http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html

Comment: What is the type of the variable holding the hex number? The operations are not the same for int vs string.

Comment: It seems somewhat unlikely that @Dany wants the low 12 bits of a string, doesn't it?

Comment: @spender:  Yes i want only lower 12 bits

Comment: I'm guessing he is reading them from a text file.

Comment: i am getting data in packet format(array of bytes)

Comment: So, you want to convert your `byte[]` into a .Net `Int32` right? If I understand your number consists of 3 bytes, right? Is one of the bits the sign?

Comment: i am getting two byte data as array[0]=0X0F and array[1]= 0XF8. and i want to combine both byte and i am getting value as 0X0FF8. and after that i am doing rest of operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

erm,

To get the right twelve bits only you could do,

```
var right12 = 0x0FFF & yourNumber;
```

To find out if it negative or positive do,

```
var positive = yourNumber >= 0;
var absoluteValue = Math.Abs(yourNumber); // Assuming yourNumber is Int32
var low12 = 0xFFF & absoluteValue;
```

---

This does a [bitwise and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) against a bit mask for the twelve bits you want to keep.

Comment: ok I will get 12 bit from above logic.But how i can find whether number is negative or positive and its value?

Comment: Do you mean just the absolute value?

Comment: @Dany Find the highest-order bit before applying the mask. If it's a negative value, it's probably encoded using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: @Jodrell With 12 bits Hex, yourNumber is never negative. You must check the bit 11 to test for negative number, but that work only if all the hex was limited to 12 bits.

Comment: @Jodrell : can you help me please'

Answer (score 1):

To check if a signed integer value is negative, you have to check its left most bit. If the bit is set, the value is negative.

However, you only have 12 bits, while an int have 32 bits. So when you put the 12 bits in a int, 20 bits are reseted to zero (aka not set). So the left most bit (#31) is not set and the int value is not seen as a negative one.

You have to check the bit #11 and set the 20 other if the 11th is set:

```
int Value = 0x0FF8;

// Check bit #11
if ((Value & 0x0800) != 0)
{
    // Set the 20 other bits to make the int value a negative one
    Value |= 0xFFFFF000;
}
```

You can also do the same thing by using short instead of int. A short only have 16 bits, so:

```
short Value = 0x0FF8;

// Check bit #11
if ((Value & 0x0800) != 0)
{
    // Set the 4 other bits to make the short value a negative one
    Value |= 0xF000;
}
```

The int version is probably the best one to use to avoid casts in the code.